# Lookup Table/s for Images

Tags: lookup-tables

Where might lookup tables be located when used for reference within images?

I understand the theory behind how LUTs work with images - i.e. 8-bit colour images storing sets of bytes instead of colour and looking up the colour values in the associated LUT to produce colour images - but I have never been told where said LUT might be stored/located.

Might they be stored elsewhere on a server and referred to in the same way that a `CSS` stylesheet might be stored in a web directory alongside a website, for example, or is there some other way that they are stored?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LUTs, or "color palettes" are typically stored in the image file header.

Check out the [PCX file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCX) for a simple example. It's usually just a list of 256x3 bytes, i.e. one byte for red component, one for green, one for blue, repeat for each 256 color index.